# Single table with multiple properties or one table per type?

Tags: sql, database, sqlalchemy

Here is my DB :

[image]

Each element represent a row, and can have several attributes. It can have multiple attributes of the same type (for example multiple boolean attributes).

I was satisfied of my design so far, but now I need to query my data with filtering and operations, and I can't figure it out.

For example, I need to sum the value of attributes with similar name. So for example, for the data :

```
[
    {"attr1": 2, "attr2": 3, "attr3": "a string"},
    {"attr1": 1, "attr2": 5, "attr3": "another string"},
]
```

If I compute the sum, I want to get : `{"attr1": 3, "attr2": 8}` (here in the results `attr3` doesn't appear because it's a string, I can't compute the sum of a string).

I can't figure out how to query this in `sqlalchemy`. I'm starting to wonder if my design is proper. Should I gather all attributes in a single table, with several properties (`value_boolean`, `value_date`, `value_float`, `value_string`) even if it means only one property won't be NULL ?

Comment: "I can't figure out how to query this in sqlalchemy", so have you figured this in plain sql?

Comment: Normal way to do this is to have one Element table with name, last_edited, and then 3 value fields: string_value, number_value, date_value.  You can also add a Type field to make it easier to understand which value to use when.  Now if you want to show a unified value just use `Coalesce(string_value, number_value, date_value)`.  You can even define that Coalesce as a defined, calculated field in the table def.

Comment: @python_user Unfortunately no, I find it easier to directly try queries in sqlalchemy. Maybe that's the wrong way...

Comment: @ChrisMaurer Since each element can have several attributes, I need at least 2 tables, right ? One Element table, and one Attribute table.

Comment: I just asked that question because I assumed you had issue with sqlachemy semantics and not the sql

Comment: Just keep adding records with same table_id and different names.  As a matter of fact you might even want to either jettison your ID field and make table_id + name your dual primary key, or add a unique index to table_id+name.  This will prevent you from adding the same attribute to the same table twice which is entirely possible with both your current design and with my initial suggested one.